# Cut off data in crystal Report when data is large

Tags: .net, crystal-reports-2008

I am working in a Restaurant Project in vb.net with crysta report 2008.In this I print a Bill in Crystal Report
for every order.my page size is 7 by 8. everything is OK.

but problem is when i add more than 25 items in bill then the bill is print
with 20 Items.

Now i want to print two bill when data is large then one page.how can i do?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

how about having the restaurant name etc in the Page Header section and rest all Billing Items in Detail section. This way every time the bill spills into second page the page header will repeat and the items will continue.
Thanks.